# DropInRequest cannot found

Tags: android, braintree, venmo, braintree-data

I have implemented `Braintree` with `Venmo`, now i want to get `DeviceData` so as described in [reference](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/advanced-fraud-tools/client-side/android/v2) link i have done everything.

build.gradle

```
compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:data-collector:2.4.0'
```

create `DropInRequest` object

```
DropInRequest dropInRequest = new DropInRequest()
                .clientToken(clientToken);
```

but it is not recognizing `DropInRequest` class. It shows

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`DropInRequest` comes under different package Drop-in. Add this to gradle.

```
compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.0.5'
```

Check [VenmoClient-Side Implementation from BrainTree](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/venmo/client-side/android/v2) which tells about integration of Drop-In and all.

See Release Info at [Braintree Android Drop-in 3.0.5 released](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/braintree-sdk-announce/fKiadTtLa6I)

Comment: I have followed link provided by BrainTree, have you checked that reference link?

Comment: @RaviRupareliya Yes I saw that link. But for integrating Venmo with BrainTree they have a different link https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/venmo/client-side/android/v2.

Comment: Also note that [Venmo payments are currently in limited release](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/venmo/configuration#email-us). If you haven't already, you'll need to contact Braintree "to determine if you're a good fit for the limited release."